# Bullet list css

Tags: css, wordpress, bullet

I'm trying to modidy bullets list on WordPress https://www.willgo.fr/. I'm using the css below but the bullets are not align.

```
ul.special_bullet li {
  list-style: none!important;
}

ul.special_bullet li:before {
  color: #00b300;
  content: "\2022";
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  left: -5px;
}
```

Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: I'd suggest to place some link to online snippet instead of the URL of a real web page. People may not want to follow links to pages that they do not know. You can use JS fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) that everybody knows and uses to share some piece of code, that you want to be looked into.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that can break your bullets is `top: -15px`.
I'd suggest to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the bullets moved when I added .
So I used:

```
.special_bullet h3 {
  display: inline-block;
 }
```